# Can't find a residue, a limit relating to $\zeta()$ (feat. Cauchy's P.V)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

$$f(s) = \zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)\Gamma(s) $$

This has a double pole at $s=0$ , and I got -1/2 , and then to find the other

$$ \lim_{s\to0} s(f(s) - \frac{-1/2}{s^2})  $$

(Actually, it is $-log\sqrt{2\pi} = \zeta'(0)$ from my book)

In my calcuation, It comes down to

$$ \lim_{s\to0} (s\zeta(s+1)\Gamma(s+1))' = 0  $$

And this should come down again to $ \zeta(1) +\Gamma'(1) = 0 $, where $\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma, $  so it means $$\lim_{s\to0} \zeta(s+1) = \gamma $$

From wikipedia, its Cauchy P.V $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon)+\zeta(1-\epsilon)}{2} = \gamma \space\space\space vs. \space\space\space \zeta(1) = \infty $$

I don't know much about Cauchy's P.V, but it's related to 'integral thing'.

Why should I use this when just getting $\lim_{s\to0} \zeta(s+1)$?

OR Is there another way to get $-log\sqrt{2\pi} = \zeta'(0)$ in the first place?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get the proper font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.